# why when I add query string into my url it gets denied by xampp ('The requested URL was not found on this server')

Tags: javascript, apache, xampp, localhost

I can run my file by this url 'http://localhost/first' : first is the folder located in xampp>htdocs
in another file there is a button that's redirect me to 'http://localhost/first' +product.name
it displays for exemple : 'http://localhost/first/shoes13' and the access get denied ('Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server') . I want that xampp accept this last url as without the product.name , just ignore it or something without removing it from the url because I need it. and access to 'http://localhost/first/shoes13' as it is 'http://localhost/first' ..
is that possible ?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example so others can help you figure out the problem.  See here about asking a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are adding is a path parameter and not a query string parameter. Path paramters need mappings in server.

With query string it should look like:
http://localhost/first?productname=shoes13

With the URL you specified you need to map the URL in server like

/first/{productname}

Comment: yeah my bad , I am talking about a path parameter not a query string , so how can I access to my file by /first/{productname}